# Samba mount is empty when mounted with nounix

Tags: ubuntu, samba, samba4

For years this has worked and today it stopped.

I have a Debian 8 server running Samba 4.2.10 to provide some shares to Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 machines on a LAN.

This morning the ubuntu machines have apparently mounted shares but they're empty.

Server `smb.conf`:

```
[global]
  workgroup = PAP
  server string = Hello there.
  obey pam restrictions = Yes
  pam password change = Yes
  unix password sync = Yes
  syslog = 0
  log file = /var/log/samba/log
  log level = 3
  socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_SNDBUF=16384
  dns proxy = No
  wins support = Yes
  valid users = pap,rich
  hosts allow = 10.0., 127.
  # shares default to rw, pap.pap, open perms
  read only = No
  force user = pap
  force group = pap
  create mask = 0666
  force create mode = 0666
  directory mask = 0777
  force directory mode = 02777

[org]
  comment = Main Files Space
  path = /home/org
```

And on the Ubuntu client (cifs-utils v6.4), I've been connecting with

```
mount -t cifs -o rw,nobrl,gid=pap,username=pap,password=****,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0666,nounix \
   //server/org /mnt/org
```

If I mount without the `nounix` option then I can see the files. The `nounix` option is important because symlinks are otherwise treated differently between Windows and Ubuntu machines. No errors are generated AFAICS.

### Edit: what do the logs say?

#### Server

The (Debian 8) **server** does not append anything to the logs (at `/var/log/samba/*`) when the share is mounted with or without `nounix`. Neither does anything show up monitoring `journalctl -u smbd`

I did ramp up Samba's logging on the server but it's kinda all or nothing and I did not see anything pertaining to the mount that was of help.

#### Client

The client (Ubuntu 16.04) does not appear to log anything in `/var/log/syslog`.

Following instructions on what looks like an old but remarkably similar [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/406466/comments/8) which are:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI
sudo dmesg -c >/dev/null
sudo mount ...
sudo ls /mount-point/
sudo dmesg -c
```

outputs nothing.

I also ran these commands after doing `echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/fs/cifs/traceSMB`. This *did* generate output (lots of hexdumped binary). I can post these hexdumps with and without the `nounix` if they're of interest...

Comment: Have you tried to mount with `nounix,noserverino` options? One thing that happens when you specify `nounix` is that inode numbers you get from the server are typically larger than 32-bit integers..

Comment: Yes, Thanks, I've tried that option, same behaviour as I experienced without it. I think everything is running 64 bit.

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: @030 I've updated the question

Comment: What changed?  Any updates that you're aware of?

Comment: Change at the client end more likely. Server only gets security updates and I would have noticed if that broke it. Nothing deliberately changed by me so hard to tell.

Comment: Two clients, same kernel, same OS, same samba version, same cifs-utils version, same perms on mount point, same share on server: one works with `nounix`, one gives the empty dir. I'm well and truly stumped.